# Laravel best practice for get data from DB

Tags: php, laravel

I'm confused about the best way to get data from DB. I have this controller (Task) that get from Task model the tasks of each customers. What's the best way to get these data?

### 1° Example

In this example I have a "general" function (getTasksCompany) that join the tables (Task and Companies). The showTasks call this function and then use where clause for get only tasks with customer code = 000001

```
    public function showTasks() {
            $tasks = $this->getTasksCompany()->where("company_code", "=", "000001")->get();

            dd($tasks);
        }

public function getTasksCompany() {
        $tasks = Task::join("companies AS c", "c.code", "=", "company_code");

        return $tasks;
    }
```

### 2° Example

In this example I have a "specific" function that get tasks from the code in the passed as argument.

```
public function showTasks2() {
        $tasks = $this->getTasksFromCompany("000001");

        dd($tasks);
    }

public function getTasksFromCompany($company_code) {
        $tasks = Task::join("companies AS c", "c.code", "=", "company_code")->where("company_code", "=", $company_code)->get();

        return $tasks;
    }
```

### 3° Example

In this example I have a "general" function (getTasksCompany) that join the tables (Task and Companies) and I use the scope defined from Task model to filter the tasks.

```
public function showTasks3() {
        $tasks = $this->getTasksCompany()->company("000001")->get();

        dd($tasks);
    }

 public function getTasksCompany() {
        $tasks = Task::join("companies AS c", "c.code", "=", "company_code");

        return $tasks;
    }

public function scopeCompany($query, $company_code) {
        return $query->where("company_code", "=", $company_code);
    }
```

My question is, what's the good practice to do? And Why?

Comment: this might help you  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I think a good practice that a lot of Frameworks implement, is Repository classes, if you need to add extra functions to the model, you create a repository class where you add all your custom database calls. Read more about the **Repository Pattern** here : https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/

Comment: please tell us which function belongs to controller and which is not.

Comment: @Amin All that function belongs to controller Task except for the scopeCompany function that belongs to Task model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding, asking for best practices would attract opinionated answer **but** generally because you use Laravel, I would try as much as possible to make use of the functionalities it provide.

While I would prefer the third example more than the others because using model `scope` helps to create and bind query builder from an instance of the model. This would make things easier when you reuse this function.

This means you don't need to statically call any query builder method since they bind to the initial model in the first place.

An example if I would do the above I would simply employ Model Relationship that would handle my `joins` under the hood:

```
//Company model
public function scopeShowTask($company_code = "000001")
{
    return $this->tasks()->where("company_code", "=", $company_code);
}

public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class, 'company_code', 'code');
}
```

Using this method helps to construct your query based on the relationship between Task and Company. In order to understand how this works, you should check out [Eloquent Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

One great advantage of using this method is that you can easily take advantage of the various method laravel provides when you declare a relationship in your model this way. To see some of them, you can check out [Querying relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

> PS: Best practice, no, maybe just a better practice given the situation. This answer is open to an *update*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you study eloquent and query builder thoroughly and that's where the best practice is.

If you use eloquent with query builder properly you won't need another function in order fetch the data that you want.

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent